# In which ways, Netflix conductor is different from a BPEL engine?

Tags: microservices

[Netflix conductor](https://netflix.github.io/conductor/) allows you to implement complex business and process flows using a JSON DSL. I do understand the scheduled nature of Conductor, still, in what way, it is different from having a BPEL engine in the good old SOA world? Also, who should own the governance and maintenance of Workflows?